# Adding a variable inside regex re.search() patern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to add a variable inside the regex patern for re.search() such as:

```
xvar=100
answer= re.search(r'(<a href=")(.+count=xvar.+?)(")', subreddit).group(2)
```

but i receive the error:

```
    nexturl = re.search(r'(<a href=")(.+count=xvar.+?)(")', subreddit).group(2) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How do i fix this to do what i want it to do?

Comment: Just use a formatted string in which the variable is substituted in the string.

Comment: I tried this: stringpatern='(<a href=")(.+count=' + xvar + '.+?)(")' but i received an error, is that what you mean?

Comment: `xvar` is an integet so cast to string.

Comment: okay i think that and the fact that i was still using r'' was the problem. Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xvar=100
answer= re.search('(<a href=")(.+count=' + str(xvar) + '.*?)(")', subreddit).group(2)
```

or

```
xvar=100
answer= re.search('(<a href=")(.+count=%s.*?)(")' % xvar, subreddit).group(2)
```

or

```
xvar=100
answer= re.search('(<a href=")(.+count={0}.*?)(")'.format(xvar), subreddit).group(2)
```

See https://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/ for more info on formatted strings

Comment: `int + string = close but no cigar`

Comment: this is actually the closest to the answer i wanted though. I see where my problem was, it was a '' issue.

Comment: @user2369869 As I said, you needed to cast to a string.

Comment: And this will all fail with `subreddit = r'<a href="something" count="100">Text</a>'`

Comment: @stribizhev, good point. I've upvoted your answer and fixed mine to use .*?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format`, and for handle the exception use a `try-except` :

```
xvar=100
try:
    answer= re.search(r'(<a href=")(.+count={}.+?)(")'.format(xvar), subreddit).group(2)
except AttributeError:
    print 'no match'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting:

```
r'(<a href=")(.+count={}.+?)(")'.format(xvar)
```

Comment: It will fail with `subreddit = r'<a href="something" count="100">Text</a>'`

Comment: @stribizhev This is *his* regex, not mine. I'm simply showing him how to interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the variable issue (you should convert an `xvar` `int` to `string` using `str()`), I think the problem is also in using `.+?`. If you replace it with `.*?` you will get a match, and `group(2)` will be accessible.

Try this code:

```
import re

xvar=100
subreddit = r'<a href="something" count="100">Text</a>'
answer= re.search( r'(<a href=")(.+count="' + str(xvar) + r'.*?)(")', subreddit).group(2)
```

Output:

```
something" count="100
```

Here is a [sample demo program in Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVWNnazVrcHpGVUU).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are 3 ways to do this (it's called formatting or interpolation, generally):

```
some_string = "dogs are cute :)"
# very basic, using concatenation: 
print "All " + some_string + " and go to heaven."
# Or, using the interpolate operator: 
print "All %s and go to heaven."    # Use %d for digits, %f for floats, %s for strings, etc. You have to be specific with the variable type. 
# Or use string format: 
print "All {} and go to heaven.".format(some_string)
```

Format is considered the 'best' practice in most scenarios, though you'll see the interpolate `%` around a lot. Check out the full format syntax at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting